# An inverse for a matrix under

Tags: matrices

Assume that $R$ is a ring and all matrices have entries in $R$.

Let $N$ be a nilpotent matrix of index $k$. If $A=I+N$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, then $A-I$ is nilpotent as well. So we have $$0=(A-I)^{k}=A_{o}+A_{e}$$ where $A_{o}$ contain the odd powers of $A$ and $A_{e}$ contain the even powers of $A$. I need a hint to show the following:

(i) $A_{o}=AU$ where $U=[(-1)^{k-1}(kI+c_{2}A^{2}+\cdots)].$ Obs. The author doesn't mention the constants in the summation. Are they elements of the ring $R$ or are they matrices?

*As I was told by QED, those coefficients are elements of the ring $R$. In fact, they are natural numbers. QED gave the following hint:
$$(A-I)^k=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}A^i\tag{1}$$
where $A^0=I$.  Then $A_{o}=-\binom{k}{1}A^1-\binom{k}{3}A^3-\cdots=(-1)^{k-1}A(\binom{k}{1}I+\binom{k}{3}A^2+\cdots)$. Then we put $U=[(-1)^{k-1}(kI+c_{3}A^{2}+\cdots)].$ We choose $k-1$ because $k$ is associated with an even power of $A$.*

(ii) Show that $U=(-1)^{k-1}(2^{k-1}I+\alpha N).$ Obs. Is $\alpha$ a matrix?

*Now $U=[(-1)^{k-1}(kI+c_{2}A^{2}+\cdots)]=(-1)^{k-1}[kI+\binom{k}{3}(I+N)^{2}+\binom{k}{5}(I+N)^{4}+\cdots]$ From $(I+N)^{2}=I+N(2I+N)$ we have $$\binom{k}{3}(I+N)^{2}=\binom{k}{3}I+\binom{k}{3}N(2I+N)$$
Analogously we have $$\binom{k}{5}(I+N)^{4}=\binom{k}{5}I+2\binom{k}{5}N(2I+N)+\binom{k}{5}N^{2}(2I+N)^{2}$$
Since the sum of odd coefficients is $2^{k-1}$ we get the first part. I think we should have something like that
$$U=(-1)^{k-1}[2^{k-1}I+\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\alpha_{i} N^{i}(2I+N)^{i}]$$*

(iii) Why does $2$ need to be an invertible element in $R$?

Comment: The constants in the summation in (i) and $\alpha$ in (ii) are elements of the ring $R$ and not matrices. Where did (iii) come from, is it relevant in this problem?

Comment: Also what is $U$? And is the second term in parenthesis really $A^3$, because multiplied with the $A$ outside the parenthesis  it will give $A^4$, and even power of $A$

Comment: The author says  that "if $2$ in a unit, then $N$ is a polynomial in $N(2I+N).$" I don't understand this either.

Comment: Just a second please.

Comment: @QED Could you please check what I have done.

Comment: What you have done is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As $A$ commutes with $I$,

$$(A-I)^k=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}A^i\tag{1}$$
where $A^0=I$.

Can you work out the rest from (1)?

Comment: I'll try. Give me some time. :)